# Proxmox, folder contents not shown

Tags: templates, iso, proxmox

I have been using proxmox v3.0-20 for some time.

Some time ago I have downloaded some iso template, and added some of mine to proxmox.
Usually when I wanted to add a new instance, I access the templates and install them.

For some reason this iso templates not showing anymore on "storage content". I know they exist because when I access proxmox via ssh I can see they are on /var/lib/vz/template/cache as usuall.

Also tried to download a new template and after finish downloading it is not shows on the list.
The backups also not showing on the list of backups.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much

Paulo

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem.
I upgraded Proxmox to 3.1 and everything back to normal.

I still don't understand what was the problem and perhaps there another solution for this problem. Anyway, if someone has the same problem, this solution could help.

Regards

Paulo Matos

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is relevant, but in proxmox, containers backups cannot be renamed... so you are stuck with how they are named... if you do rename them, they will not show in the webinterface.